# Editing a variable length list. View Model IEnumerable<> property is comming null from post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to edit a variable length list, so I've followed [Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) and [Ivan Zlatev's blog](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) and comes to this.
Model:

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Тип")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Значение")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public long Owner { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public SpecTreeNodeType OwnerType { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Security.Models.TagViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tag editor";
}

<h2>Tag editor</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("EditTags", "TreeView", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <div id="editorRows">            
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {        
            Html.RenderPartial("_partialTagEditor", Model.ElementAt(i));            
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add tag", "AddTag", null, new { id = "addItem" });
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" />
}

<script>
    $("#editorRows").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function () {        
        $(this).closest("div.editorRow").remove();        
    });

    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Partial view:

```
@model Security.Models.TagViewModel

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TagViewModel"))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Value)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Owner)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OwnerType)        
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    }
</div>
```

Post action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditTags(IEnumerable<TagViewModel> tagList)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Fiddler shows, that EditTags post request contains required data:

```
TagViewModel.Index  c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c
TagViewModel[c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c].Name Length
TagViewModel[c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c].Value    100 - 200
TagViewModel[c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c].Id   1
TagViewModel[c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c].Owner    3
TagViewModel[c1ec8d7c-cfc9-4cdc-b32c-6446d4bb476c].OwnerType    value
TagViewModel.Index  9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670
TagViewModel[9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670].Name Width
TagViewModel[9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670].Value    10 - 20
TagViewModel[9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670].Id   2
TagViewModel[9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670].Owner    3
TagViewModel[9fad7d46-f6f6-4cd7-80be-41e1b5011670].OwnerType    value
TagViewModel.Index  30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b
TagViewModel[30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b].Name wqe
TagViewModel[30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b].Value    qwe
TagViewModel[30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b].Id   0
TagViewModel[30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b].Owner    0
TagViewModel[30048799-116c-4eba-9010-580c681e6a5b].OwnerType    value
```

But in controllers's EditTags action method tagList is null. I'm stuck and have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: You model does not have a property named `TagViewModel`. You need to generate he names as `[xxxx].Name`, `[xxxx].Id` etc. It would need to be `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(""))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Not working for me. Fiddler shows `.Index fdc9158c-6c45-427f-bbd9-3b9add9c896f
[fdc9158c-6c45-427f-bbd9-3b9add9c896f].Name Length`. But still no luck.

Comment: Try it with `Html.BeginCollectionItem("tagList")` since that's the name of your parameter (not sure why the helper would add the `.` to `Index` although `[fdc9158c-6c45-427f-bbd9-3b9add9c896f].Name` is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you reused a lot of code from this [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). You have one small error. When you use Steven's custom helper you provide wrong name to it:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TagViewModel"))
```

But it should be:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("tagList"))
```

Because your `EditTags` action has a parameter named `tagList`.

You can also post a collection as part of main model. So your model might look like that:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Tags"))
```